# how to play flash in WPF application

Tags: wpf, flash, winforms-interop

I have a WPF application and I want to play flash movies in it.

I used the WInforms active X control as described in [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html)

It worked partially, but now whenever I run the application it crashes saying "InvalidActiveXStateException"

does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
You can use a AxShockwaveFlash.
see [this link](http://www.pooredesign.com/blog/?p=d9165e80-d075-4faf-8a10-bfaf17769198)

Comment: The link does not work anymore. Could you provide an alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend adding a WebBrowser control to your WPF application and allow IE to load the URL of the Flash Movie directly; which in turn would load the Flash Plugin.  You will need to build your WPF application as x86 only for this to work on x64 Windows.